Blazor: The name 'Acti' does not exist in the current context
I'm getting the following Error:

The name 'Acti' does not exist in the current context

In the code behind file acti is declared as a string:
[Parameter]
public string? Acti { get; set; }

ClientEditForm.Razor:
@namespace Views.Components.Clients
@page "/client/{clientNo:int}/{Acti}"

<ClientEditFormComponent Acti="@Acti" />


I think you used the wrong name.

You seems like recursively using the ClientEditForm Component. As the Component filename is ClientEditForm.razor. The Code behind file must have the same name ClientEditForm.razor.cs
    public partial class ClientEditForm
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string? Acti { get; set; }
    }

And the Child Component name should be the same.


Tnx Qiang, that was indeed the problem. Tnx again
